# copy every line from a text file that contains a number greater than 5000

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

Hi I've tried many solutions to similar questions and none have seemed to work for me. I have a text file where each line has an undefined length of numbers after the string " length_ ". How can I select out all the lines where that number is equal to or greater than 5000? This has been the cleanest looking code attempt I’ve tried so far, but it still just produces an empty file (even though file1 definitely contains lines with numbers greater than 5000)

```
grep --regexp="length_\"[5-9][0-9]\{3,\}\"" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

example info within input text file:
/file/path/xx00:>TEXT_1_length_81903_cov_10.5145_
/file/path/xx01:>TEXT_2_length_348971_cov_13.6753_
/file/path/xx02:>TEXT_3_length_4989_cov_11.9516_
/file/path/xx03:>TEXT_4_length_29811_cov_13.7948_
/file/path/xx03:>TEXT_5_length_2567_cov_13.7948_

desired example info within output text file:
/file/path/xx00:>TEXT_1_length_81903_cov_10.5145_
/file/path/xx01:>TEXT_2_length_348971_cov_13.6753_
/file/path/xx03:>NODE_4_length_29811_cov_13.7948_

Comment: Please post a few lines from a sample input file, and make up a corresponding results file (i.e. show us the exact input you have and the exact output you expect).

Comment: Do you want greater than or less than?

Comment: Given that your actual input file doesn't start with "length_", I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, using awk, to print lines from a file that contain a number after the string "length_" that is less than or equal to 5000:

```
awk '{sub("length_", "", $0); if ($0 <= 5000) { print "length_"$0 } }' input
```

It simply tells `awk` to strip off the "length_" string, then compare the remaining part of the line to 5000; if it's less than or equal to 5000, print "length_" and the remainder of the line. Your Q's subject line says (at the time) "greater than 5000", so if that's the actual desire, simply change the comparison in awk:

```
awk '{sub("length_", "", $0); if ($0 > 5000) { print "length_"$0 } }' input
```

---

Given the *actual* file format, the awk command can be simplified considerably:

```
awk -F_ '$4 > 5000' input
```

or

```
awk -F_ '$4 <= 5000' input
```

by telling awk to split the fields based on underscores, then comparing the fourth field to 5000. If the comparison is true, then (by default) print.

Comment: This second solution using the underscore as a field separator and then filtering the column containing the numbers for greater than 5000 works perfectly. nifty solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E '_length_([5-9][0-9]{3}|[0-9]{5,})_' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

outputs lines containing:

- `_length_` followed by either:

  - `5` - `9` and 3 more digits (5000-9999) **or**
  - 5 or more digits (10000+)
- followed by `_`.